# Resteasy service on wildfly not found

Tags: java, rest, web-services, wildfly, resteasy

I'm tryng to call a rest service written witch resteasy deployed on wildfly 23. But when I try to call it, I get 404 or a not found.

----------------------------------------------------------------------RecipesRestResource

```
@Path("/recipes")
@Produces("application/json")
public class RecipesRestResource {

    private RecipesRequestHandler recipesRequestHandler;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllRecipes() {
        List<Recipe> recipes = recipesRequestHandler.getAllRecipes();
        return Response.ok(recipes).build();
    }

}
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------RecipesRequestHandler

```
public class RecipesRequestHandler {

    private final RecipesPresentation recipesPresentation;

    public RecipesRequestHandler() {
        recipesPresentation = new RecipesPresentation();
    }

    public List<Recipe> getAllRecipes() {
        return recipesPresentation.getAllRecipes();
    }

}
```

---

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

}
```

----------------------------------------------------------------------web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

  <display-name>My Application</display-name>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>org.vinyls.rest.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

UPDATE

Are there any othere configuration to do in order to call an endpoint and receive a response?

Comment: What is the URI you're using?

Comment: I'm using http://localhost:8080/RecipesDBAccess/api/recipes and now I get a:
RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/RecipesDBAccess/api/recipes/

Comment: I would remove the RESTEasy servlet entry. You don’t need that. What is the name of your WAR?